# Crystal Report display only one line on detail section of group

Tags: crystal-reports

My report is shown like this :

> group header (empty)
>   -----------------   30/04/2013          FR 000000000000    Test    AMINOLONE
>   Detail section    30/04/2013          FR 111111111111    Test    AMINOLONE
>   -----------------   30/04/2013          FR 222222222222    Test    AMINOLONE
>   group footer       FR 000000000000 FR 111111111111 FR 222222222222`

And I want it to look like this :

> group header (empty)
>   Detail section      30/04/2013                  -          Test    AMINOLONE
>   group footer      FR 000000000000 FR 111111111111 FR 222222222222`

Only one record in the detail section per group but I don't know how to do it.  Does someone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this can be Solution to your problem

Step1: Create a parameter using Parameter Fields -> RightClick -> Give Parameter Name and Press OK.  (example: norows)

Step2: Supress with condition:

```
         {Products.ProductID} <= {?norows}
```